# Allow RangeAttribute to apply to properties in sub-viewmodels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am using a viewmodel to pass data to my Razor view with jquery unobtrusive validation and standard attribute decoration (MVC 3.0).  My viewmodel looks like this (ignore the summarized names):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyViewItem Item { get; set; }
   public MyViewItem Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewItem
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
   public CustomEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is decorate the Item and Item2 values on the MyViewModel with different range attributes.  However these do not appear when I use the *EditorFor* extension of *Html* as they are not on the specific Value property that is used.

i.e.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   [Range(0,100)] // will actually be applied on the Item.Value property
   public MyViewItem Item { get; set; }

   [Range(50,60)] // will actually be applied on the Item.Value property
   public MyViewItem Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this by custom attributes or some other form i.e. custom data binding, custom attributes etc

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to put up with two different types, you could subclass MyViewItem and have the derived class have a different RangeValidationAttribute defined for it.

Comment: Hadn't really thought of that cheers.  However I would like to use this MyViewModel in lots of different cases and would prefer not to have to make a subclass for each of these.